# NoClassDefFoundError hadoop/yarn/client/YarnClientImpl

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, giraph

I installed giraph-1.0.0 on my 2-node cluster, built with hadoop version 2.0.4-alpha where as i have hadoop 2.7.1 installed on my cluster. When I tried to run the giraph example for Simple Shortest Path Vertex, I got the following NoClassDefFoundError.

```
hadoop jar $GIRAPH_HOME/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.0.0-for-hadoop-2.0.4-alpha-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsVertex -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/hduser/input/tinygraph.txt -of org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/hduser/output/shortestpaths -w 1
```

The error is

```
16/08/05 14:26:09 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge input format specified. Ensure your InputFormat does not require one.
16/08/05 14:26:09 WARN job.GiraphConfigurationValidator: Output format vertex index type is not known
16/08/05 14:26:09 WARN job.GiraphConfigurationValidator: Output format vertex value type is not known
16/08/05 14:26:09 WARN job.GiraphConfigurationValidator: Output format edge value type is not known
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/YarnClientImpl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 21 more
```

The command I used for building giraph is this.

```
mvn -Phadoop_yarn -DskipTests -Dhadoop.version=2.0.4-alpha clean package
```

I am not sure if I need to rebuild apache giraph or it is something else which is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that Giraph 1.0 works with hadoop 2.7.1? Maybe you should try with Giraph 1.1.0 or wait until Giraph 1.2.0 is completed

Comment: I'll try with giraph-1.1.0